# Some inequalities for holomorphic function on unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

D is a open unit disk centered at 0.

I can figure out why |f(z)|<1 (by using maximum modulus theorem)

also I can show the latter inequality.

My attempt is using latter term is less than |Z| which is trivial.

(But I think this is not right way.)

Problem is I can not show First inequality.

How can I show this one?

Can you give me a any little clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Trial: Using Harnack's inequality, (Very similar form) But It is not a harmonic function... So Fail.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $|a|<1,$ let $g_a(z) = (a-z)/(1-\bar a z).$ These are well known automorphisms of $\mathbb D,$ the unit disc. Note that $g_{f(0)}\circ f$ is a self map of $\mathbb D$ that takes $0$ to $0.$ By the Schwarz lemma,

$$|g_{f(0)}(f(z))|\le |z|, z\in \mathbb D.$$

Write that out in all its glory and do the silliest things you can think of with absolute values and those inequalities should fall out.

Comment: Wow. It looks working! I'll check very soon. Thanks!!

Comment: Oh, I was completely wrong. The thing what i considered solved ( latter inequality) is obtained by your suggestion, Not my idea. But again, I can't show First inequality.

Comment: I solved it! Thank you.

Comment: Good for you. Now how about a nice little √ ?